# combining lists: three lists into one new list

Tags: python, list

I have three lists that contain x,y and z positions. For example:

```
x = [10,20,1]
y = [10,15,2]
z = [12,23,3]
```

I want to create a list using these that looks like:

```
xyz = [[10,10,12], [20,15,23], [1,2,3]]
```

These lists are huge (1 million entries).
What is a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you do not need to access all values for sure, I'd suggest to not create the actual list, but create an accessor function that builds coordinated triples on demand?

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but I need to access all values and so I need a list of lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function:

```
>>> x = [10,20,1]
>>> y = [10,15,2]
>>> z = [12,23,3]
>>> zip(x, y, z)
[(10, 10, 12), (20, 15, 23), (1, 2, 3)]
```

This produces a list of tuples. If you absolutely need a list of lists, coerce those tuples manually:

```
>>> [list(t) for t in zip(x, y, z)]
[[10, 10, 12], [20, 15, 23], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Note that in Python 3, [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns a lazy iterator instead of a list (the same as [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) in Python 2). If your lists are that big, that may actually be preferable, but remember that iterators aren't subscriptable.

Comment: Thank you. I need list of lists. Time is off essence to me. I tried your code and it works. Although I am looking for something that is fast and does not need an intermediate step (here convert to tuple).

Answer (score 2):

For Python 2.x you can use izip:

```
from itertools import izip

for a,b,c in izip(x,y,z):
    # do something
```

This iterates across the lists instead of copying their data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a manual way of doing it (if you're interested):

```
>>> xyz = []
>>> x = [10, 20, 1]
>>> y = [10, 15, 2]
>>> z = [12, 23, 3]
>>> 
>>> for num in range(3): #Change 3 to however many numbers u want
...     xyz.append([x[num], y[num], z[num]])
... 
>>> print xyz
[[10, 10, 12], [20, 15, 23], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: With much of this page, it would be good to add "assert len(x) == len(y) and len(y) == len(z)" and/or use zip_longest().  Also, in 2.x izip is sometimes better than zip, though in 3.x zip is the way to go.

Comment: Agreed. They definitely need to all have same lengths. I just thought this route would be interesting because its somewhat manual in comparison to zip.